# Optarg is alway null

Tags: c++, getopt

Optarg is always null. Application crashes.

```
static const char* const short_options = "a:h:p";
static const struct option long_options[] =
{
    { "address",    1, NULL, 'a' },
    { "help",       0, NULL, 'h' },
    { "port",       1, NULL, 'p' }
};
```

I tried to add null string to the long_options, but it did not help.

```
static const struct option long_options[] =
{
    { "address",    1, NULL, 'a' },
    { "help",       0, NULL, 'h' },
    { "port",       1, NULL, 'p' },
    {0,             0, NULL,  0 }
};
```

but it did not help.

[There](http://linux.die.net/man/3/optarg) is example of the optarg using. I use optarg with the same way, but get null.

```
do {
        nextOption = getopt_long(argc, argv, short_options, long_options, NULL);
        switch (nextOption)
        {
        case 'a':
        {
            //do something
        }
            break;
        case 'h':
            printf(usage_template);
            exit(0);
        case 'p':
        {
            long value;
            char* end;
            value = strtol(optarg, &end, 10);//OPTARG IS NULL
            if (*end != '\0')
            {
                printf(usage_template);
            }
            port = (uint16_t)htons(value);
        }
            break;
        case '?':
            printf(usage_template);
            exit(0);
        case -1:
            break;
        default:
            exit(0);
        }
    } while (nextOption != -1);
```

Can anybody help me with this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like your "p" option isn't followed by a colon, so getopt isn't expecting it to have an argument.

Comment: is there any way to verify or fix it?

Comment: add a colon after p in short_options

Comment: > I tried to add null string to the long_options, but it did not help.
     
Optarg is also null for the 'a' option

Comment: I got it working on my machine without much effort, so I'm not sure what the issue is you your end.  You're not declaring optarg anywhere, are you?

Comment: No..I'm not declaring optard anywhere

Comment: Yeah, I don't know what to tell you.  The code works on my machine, with "a:h:p:" for short_options, and a null option at the end of long_options.

Comment: @c_dubs  Hey Dubs, good catch here.  I'm reading this post almost three years later, and you spotted my problem as well as the OP's....  Nice!